# mysqli array doesn't work outside the class in php

Tags: php, class, mysqli, while-loop

I have the following class:

```
  class countries {
        protected $_table = 'countries';

        public function __construct() {
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
        }

        public function dropdown_menu() {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->_table ORDER BY name ASC";
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die ($this->mysqli->error);

            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $results[] = array('iso' => $row['iso'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'flag' => $row['flag']);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I used outside the class:

```
    $countries = new countries();
    $countries->dropdown_menu();
    $results = $countries;

    foreach($results as $xresult)
    {
        $template->newBlock('dropdown_menu');
        $template->assign('iso', $xresult['iso']);
    }
```

This doensn't work. When i use

```
    foreach($results as $xresult)
    {
        $template->newBlock('dropdown_menu');
        $template->assign('iso', $xresult['iso']);
    }
```

Inside the class in the dropdown_menu function it works.

print_r ($results) outside the class gives the following result:

```
countries Object ( [_table:protected] => countries [mysqli] => mysqli Object ( ) )
```

How can i use $results outside the class?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new $results field in your class

```
protected $results;
```

Define a getter method for the $results in your class...

```
public function getCountries() {
    return $this->results;
}
```

And use it to assign your array to the $results variable.

```
$results = $countries->getCountries();
```

Alternatively you may also return your results within dropdown_menu() method.

```
public function dropdown_menu() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->_table ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die ($this->mysqli->error);

    $results = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $results[] = array('iso' => $row['iso'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'flag' => $row['flag']);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

And `$results = $countries->dropdown_menu();` will give you results.

Comment: You may make $_table public too

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code. You are not using your $results array in your dropdown_menu() method. Make it protected and return with a new function. You might also return $results array in your dropdown_menu() method too.

Comment: Check for syntax errors. I have not tested it. Change $this->$results; to $this->results;

Answer (score 0):

Make `dropdown_menu()` return `$results[]` or have `$results` as a public member of the class.